# How do you convert a Time Range (19:00-20:00) to a TimeStamp/Date Time object?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, machine-learning

My DF has a Column Time with a range of 1 hour. 19:00-20:00, 20:00-21:00,   21:00-22:00 and so on. I have another Column with a recorded Value in these Times, like 50 , 40, 10.

I want to know at what Hour of the Day is the Value the highest etc..
Is there a way I can convert the time from range to just single value like 19:00 and then extract the hour?

```
Df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(Df['Time']) I tried this but got error 

Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 19:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then convert values to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['19:00-20:00', '20:00-21:00', '21:00-22:00']})

df[['first', 'second']] = (df['Time'].str.split('-', expand=True)
                                     .add(':00')
                                     .apply(pd.to_timedelta))
print (df)
          Time    first   second
0  19:00-20:00 19:00:00 20:00:00
1  20:00-21:00 20:00:00 21:00:00
2  21:00-22:00 21:00:00 22:00:00

print (df.dtypes)
Time               object
first     timedelta64[ns]
second    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Or to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df[['first', 'second']] = df['Time'].str.split('-', expand=True).apply(pd.to_datetime)
print (df)
          Time               first              second
0  19:00-20:00 2019-08-04 19:00:00 2019-08-04 20:00:00
1  20:00-21:00 2019-08-04 20:00:00 2019-08-04 21:00:00
2  21:00-22:00 2019-08-04 21:00:00 2019-08-04 22:00:00

print (df.dtypes)
Time              object
first     datetime64[ns]
second    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Here is possible easy way extract parts of datetimes, e.g. hours, times...:

```
df['hour1'] = df['first'].dt.hour
df['time1'] = df['first'].dt.time
print (df)
          Time               first              second  hour1     time1
0  19:00-20:00 2019-08-04 19:00:00 2019-08-04 20:00:00     19  19:00:00
1  20:00-21:00 2019-08-04 20:00:00 2019-08-04 21:00:00     20  20:00:00
2  21:00-22:00 2019-08-04 21:00:00 2019-08-04 22:00:00     21  21:00:00

print (df.dtypes)
Time              object
first     datetime64[ns]
second    datetime64[ns]
hour1              int64
time1             object
dtype: object
```